# How would you extend a Channel?

Tags: netty

I need a little help with Netty. I was wondering how would you extend the Channel interface and add my own methods to it and make Netty use it (or cast to it)?

Matt.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is actual for netty 4.1.25.Final.

First extend your channel type

```
public class ExtendedNioChannel extends NioSocketChannel implements Channel {
    private volatile boolean handshakeComplete;
    // more custom fields and methods
}
```

If you want to use it for client bootstap just pass that class to it.

```
 Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
                b.group(workerGroup);
                b.channel(ExtendedNioChannel.class);
```

For server bootstrap you need to override NioServerSocketChannel and pass NioServerSocketChannel.class to ServerBootstrap.

```
public class ExtendedNioServerChannel extends NioServerSocketChannel {
    private static final InternalLogger logger = InternalLoggerFactory.getInstance(NioServerSocketChannel.class);

    @Override
    protected int doReadMessages(List<Object> buf) throws Exception {
        SocketChannel ch = SocketUtils.accept(javaChannel());

        try {
            if (ch != null) {
                buf.add(new ExtendedNioChannel(this, ch));
                return 1;
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            logger.warn("Failed to create a new channel from an accepted socket.", t);

            try {
                ch.close();
            } catch (Throwable t2) {
                logger.warn("Failed to close a socket.", t2);
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
}

 ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(acceptGroup, workerGroup)
                    .channel(BtcNioServerChannel.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess a better solution would be to "wrap" the Channel into your class store the class in a ChannelLocal or in the ChannelHandlerContext. Then jsut retrieve your implementation and use it. This will allow you to switch between NIO and OIO without the need to worry about the implementation.

I'm doing something similar in niosmtp:
https://github.com/normanmaurer/niosmtp/blob/master/src/main/java/me/normanmaurer/niosmtp/transport/netty/NettySMTPClientSession.java

This also helps you to decouble your code.

To provide your own channel you would need to hack the socket implementation. But as I think you should avoid it whenever possible.